# Count number of words in a sentence excluding punctuation and more than one space between words

Tags: c++, string, boolean, word-count

I'm trying to create a program that counts the number of words in sentence(s) yet when I find a space or a punctuation(?,!,:,;, or .) I cannot assume that the next character will be a letter. If I'm looking for a letter I need to skip over ALL spaces and punctuations until I find something that is neither a space nor a punctuation. I also need to take into consideration that there may be more than one space between words. I wrote a punctuation function:

```
bool is_punctuation (string character)

{

    if (character == "!")
        return true;
    else if (character == "?")
        return true;
    else if (character == ";")
        return true;
    else if (character == ":")
        return true;
    else if (character == ".")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I used it for finding the number of sentences a user enters. I now need to find word count though and am having difficulty finding a way to do so without using space location. I've gotten this far with the function but need some help! Any advice is greatly appreciated :)

```
void num_sentence (string phrase)

{

    int num_sentence = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
    {
        if (is_punctuation(phrase.substr(i,1))== true)
            num_sentence++;
    }
```

Comment: How many sentences do you see???

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it makes no sense to use a `std::string` for a single character. That's what `char` is for.

Now, it's going to be much easier to do it the other way around: to check if a character is a letter, rather than punctuation. That's easy: whether the character is in the range a-z or A-Z. For this situation it's also a good idea to include the apostrophe, so "it's", for example, looks like a single word:

```
bool is_letter(char c)
{
    return ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || c == '\'')
         ? true:false;
}
```

The other problem you have is how to define a word. Look at any sentence. Where do you see each word begin? When you see a letter. When does each word end? When you see something else other than a letter.

You don't count the number of punctuation characters. You don't care if it's one, two, three, or more non-letter characters between the individual words.

When you scan a sentence, from start to finish, you scan it one character at a time. As soon as you see a letter, that's the start of the next word. When you no longer see a letter, that's the end of the word, then you just continue looking until you see the next letter. That's going to be the next word.

In other words, if the previous character you saw was not a letter, but the current character is a letter, you just saw the start of another word.

Now, all you have to do is translate this to code:

```
size_t num_words(const std::string &sentence)
{
    bool previous_char_was_letter=false;
    size_t n=0;

    for (char c:sentence)
    {
        bool this_char_is_letter=is_letter(c);

        if (!previous_char_was_letter && this_char_is_letter)
             ++n;

        previous_char_was_letter=this_char_is_letter;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Now, doesn't this read exactly like my earlier description, translated to code?